# Umbraco Form - Remove time from Datepicker date in email

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-contour

I have a form that contains a Datepicker and in the email that is sent on submission the date is formatted with a time.

How do I remove the time from the date?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change the property to just `Date`, without the time element, or you can use `ToString()` method for the `DateTime` within C#:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

The format without time would look something like this:

```
yourDate.ToString("DD/MM/YYYY");
```